# Jacobian of a function $\mathbf{R}_2 \to \mathbf{S}_2$

Tags: real-analysis

It's a very short question.

For a function $f: \mathbf{R}_2 \to \mathbf{S}_2$, how do you define the jacobian?
Could you define jacobian even when the target space is not $\mathbf{R}_n$?

Comment: You can define the Jacobian of a map between any two smooth manifolds: it's given by the induced map on tangent spaces (at some point).

Comment: For scalar integrals, if I'm not mistaken, if you have a diffeomorphism $f$ from open subsets of $\Bbb{R}^m$ to $\Bbb{R}^m$ where $m \leq n$ you can perform a change of variables by substituting and multiplying the integrand by $\sqrt{\det{(J^TJ)}}$ where $J$ is the matrix of partial derivatives of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you need to take the Jacobian of a local representative. So if you have a map $$ F:M \to N, \ \text{where} \ M \ \text{and} \ N \ \text{are smooth manifolds} $$ you can compute something called the pushforward, which, in coordinates, is the Jacobian of the local representative of $F$. Here's a relevant wiki:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)

In our case, we have a general $m$-dimensional target space and $$ F \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to M. $$ If you want to compute the differential locally (say at $p=(x, y)$) take the Jacobian of $$ \phi \circ F \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^m $$ where $U$ is an open set containing $p$ and $\phi \colon F(U) \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a coordinate chart of $F(U)$. Of course, this is coordinate based; there's a lot more interesting things going down under the hood!